# how can I create a dynamic helper function for db query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, parse-platform

I have a list of categories I need to select from a database in numerous locations throughout my app.

So far I've been throwing the query in the call back chain for every since usage.

I'd like to just grab it in a single location so it's DRY if I ever need to modify it.

basically:

```
function() {
    var categoryList = {};
    var Category = Parse.Object.extend("Category");
    var categoryQuery = new Parse.Query(Category);
    categoryQuery.find(function(categories) {

        categories.forEach(function(item) {
            item=item.toJSON();
            categoryList[item.objectId] = item.Name;
        });

    });

    return categoryList;
}
```

But I'm uncertain where to place it, and I realize that the way it's written there categoryList is going to be empty.  How can I create a helper function that will provide me that result that I can use everywhere?

I was thinking I could put it in a external file and use require, but I tried:

```
module.exports = {};
module.exports = function(fn) {

    <code>

    fn['categoryList'] = categoryList;

    return fn;
}(module.exports);
```

And that didn't seem to work.  I put the require in app.js and everytime it was included, parse would say "Update failed with Could not load triggers."

I'm quite stumped and rather new to node/parse.  Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

*helper.js*

```
var lib = require('lib');

// exports functions
exports.help_a = function (...) { };
exports.help_b = function (...) { };
```

*app.js*

```
// imports heplers functions
helper = require('./helper.js');

//call
helper.help_a(...);
helper.help_a(...);
```

---

**Option 2**

*helper.js*

```
// exports module as function
module.exports = function (...) { };
```

*app.js*

```
helper = require('./helper.js');
helper(...);
```